# How to get Spring Data Jpa FindFirst1000() without any property

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a huge collection of data in a repository which is extending `JpaRepository`. For demo purpose I only want to show first 1000 results.

I know I can use `Slice<T> findAll(Pageable pageable)` query if I create new repository which extends `CrudRepository`. But for a simple demo creating a new repository is a overkill for me. So is it possible?

Example:
What I want to have:

```java
@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {
  Collection<Address> findFirst1000();
}
```

Comment: I feel that your can work as this, did you test it? try `List<Address> findFirst1000();`

Comment: Yes I did. Because there is no property mentioned I'm getting `PropertyReferenceException: No property findFirst1000 found for type Address!`

Comment: can you try `findFirst1000ByOrderById()`

Comment: @YCF_L, I tried but now I'm getting `IllegalArgumentException: No parameter available for part id SIMPLE_PROPERTY (1): [Is, Equals] NEVER.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't out of the box solution, but there are 2-3 approaches, which are easy to implement. You can take a look at that tutorial, where they struggle with the same thing: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-limit-query-results